# RabbitMQ creating queues and bindings from command line

Tags: rabbitmq

If I have RabbitMQ installed on my machine, is there a way to create a message queue from the command line and bind it to a certain exchange without using a client?

I think it is not possible, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Install the [RabbitMQ management plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html). It comes with a command line tool which you can use to configure all of your queues/exchanges/etc.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit?  Visiting that page doesn't reveal anything like what you've described.  Are you talking about the `load_definitions` variable and corresponding file?  Or the description of using the HTTP API with `curl`?  I was hoping for something a little more user-friendly than manually building http reqs.

Comment: To answer my own question, use `rabbitmqadmin` on the command line.  `rabbitmqadmin help subcommands` seems to be the best documentation.

Answer (score 152):

**Summary:**

Other answers are good alternatives to what was asked for. Below are commands you can use from the command line.

First, do all the necessary prep work, e.g. install rabbit, `rabbitmqadmin`, and `rabbitctl`. The idea is to use commands from `rabbitmqctl` and `rabbitmqadmin`. You can see some command examples: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html

**Example Commands/Setup:**

The following commands should give you the majority if not all of what you need:

```
# Get the cli and make it available to use.
wget http://127.0.0.1:15672/cli/rabbitmqadmin
chmod +x rabbitmqadmin
mv rabbitmqadmin /etc/rabbitmq
```

**Add a user and permissions**

```
rabbitmqctl add_user testuser testpassword
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags testuser administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / testuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

**Make a virtual host and Set Permissions**

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost Some_Virtual_Host
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p Some_Virtual_Host guest ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

**Make an Exchange**

```
./rabbitmqadmin declare exchange --vhost=Some_Virtual_Host name=some_exchange type=direct
```

**Make a Queue**

```
./rabbitmqadmin declare queue --vhost=Some_Virtual_Host name=some_outgoing_queue durable=true
```

**Make a Binding**

```
./rabbitmqadmin --vhost="Some_Virtual_Host" declare binding source="some_exchange" destination_type="queue" destination="some_incoming_queue" routing_key="some_routing_key"
```

**Alternative Way to Bind with Python**

The following is an alternative to command line binding, as I've had issues with it sometimes and found the following python code to be more reliable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

rabbitmq_host = "127.0.0.1"
rabbitmq_port = 5672
rabbitmq_virtual_host = "Some_Virtual_Host"
rabbitmq_send_exchange = "some_exchange" 
rabbitmq_rcv_exchange = "some_exchange"
rabbitmq_rcv_queue = "some_incoming_queue"
rabbitmq_rcv_key = "some_routing_key"

outgoingRoutingKeys = ["outgoing_routing_key"]
outgoingQueues = ["some_outgoing_queue "]

# The binding area
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(rabbitmq_user, rabbitmq_password)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(rabbitmq_host, rabbitmq_port, rabbitmq_virtual_host, credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_bind(exchange=rabbitmq_rcv_exchange, queue=rabbitmq_rcv_queue, routing_key=rabbitmq_rcv_key)

for index in range(len(outgoingRoutingKeys)):
    channel.queue_bind(exchange=rabbitmq_send_exchange, queue=outgoingQueues[index], routing_key=outgoingRoutingKeys[index])
```

The above can be run as part of a script using python. Notice I put the outgoing stuff into arrays, which will allow you to iterate through them. This should make things easy for deploys.

**Last Thoughts**

I think the above should get you moving in the right direction, use google if any specific commands don't make sense or read more with `rabbitmqadmin help subcommands`. I tried to use variables that explain themselves.

Comment: Great! thanks for the step by step guide. In case rabbitmqadmin is throwing Access refused error, consider adding '-u testuser -p testpassword' at the end of command.

Answer (score 26):

Create Exchange:

```
rabbitmqadmin -u {user} -p {password} -V {vhost} declare exchange name={name} type={type}
```

Create Queue:

```
rabbitmqadmin -u {user} -p {password} -V {vhost} declare queue name={name}
```

Bind Queue to Exchange:

```
rabbitmqadmin -u {user} -p {password} -V {vhost} declare binding source={Exchange} destination={queue}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Linux Debian, there's a package called [amqp-tools](https://github.com/typeduck/amqp-tools). Install it with

```
apt-get install amqp-tools
```

You can then use command line such as amqp-publish to send messages to your queue

```
amqp-publish -e exchange_name -b "your message"
```

Then you can collect message(s) from the queue using

```
amqp-get -q queue_name
```

or

```
amqp-consume -q queue_name
```

There are also (command line) examples from [rabbitmq-c](http://alanxz.github.io/rabbitmq-c/docs/0.5.0/index.html) package / library. After you build it, you can send messages through command line such as

```
amqp_sendstring localhost 5672 amq.direct test "hello world"
```

Have fun ...

Comment: How would you create a queue and exchange using this?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe a little late to the party but I've done so using CURL.

For queues:

```
curl -i -u RABBITUSER:RABBITPASSWORD -H "content-type:application/json" \
-XPUT -d'{"durable":true}' \
http://192.168.99.100:15672/api/queues/%2f/QUEUENAME
```

And for bindings

```
curl -i -u RABBITUSER:RABBITPASSWORD -H "content-type:application/json" \
-XPOST -d"{\"routing_key\":\"QUEUENAME\"}" \
http://192.168.99.100:15672/api/bindings/%2f/e/EXCHANGENAME/q/QUEUENAME
```

Note 192.168.99.100:15672 points to my RMQ Management

Comment: Only this helped me... Added this inside my DockerFile... works like a charm. Thank you. :-)

Comment: This returned 404 for me but this worked: ```curl -i -u RABBITUSER:RABBITPASSWORD -H "content-type:application/json" -XPUT -d'{"durable":true}' http://localhost:15672/rabbitmq/api/queues/%2f/QUEUENAME```

Comment: Here's the API reference in general (which is unreasonably hard to find, imo) - https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_9/priv/www/api/index.html

Answer (score 4):

`rabbitmqctl`, the provided command line interface, doesn't expose the ability to create a queue and bind it.

It, however, is quite trivial to do it with a quick script though, and the RabbitMQ getting started guide shows several examples of it, both on the publisher as well as the consumer side.

```
#do some work to connect
#do some work to open a channel
channel.queue_declare(queue='helloworld')
```

I'm glossing over connecting, but it's a literal one liner to create a queue.  The operation is also idempotent, meaning you can include the statement in a script and be safe, knowing that it won't keep recreating the queue or blowing out an existing one of the same name.

Answer (score 3):

**Create RabbitMq Exchange, Queue and Bindings dynamically from CLI on Windows**

I already had a RabbitMQ Server installed and running with multiple queue and exchange and now wanted to create it on the fly from command line. I know it is an old question but I thought giving out this information will be helpful.

Following is what I did:

Setup

1. Downloaded and installed Python 2.6.6-201008-24 Windows x86-64 MSI installer , any version of python,
2. Download RabbitMqAdmin: RabbitMq Web User Interface has a link Command Line which navigates to http://server-name:15672/cli/ (server-name: server on which rabbitmq is installed) *alternatively*,use the above url and save the file as *rabbitmqadmin.exe* in the python exe location

eg: C:\Python26
C:\Python26\python
C:\Python26\rabbitmqadmin.exe

Code:in a batch file used the below commands

1. Create exchange:

```
c:\python26\python.exe rabbitmqadmin.exe declare exchange name=*ExchangeName1* type=topic durable=true
```

2. Create queue:

```
c:\python26\python.exe rabbitmqadmin.exe declare queue name=*NameofQueue1* durable=true
```

3. Create binding:

```
c:\python26\python.exe rabbitmqadmin.exe declare binding source=ExchangeName1 destination_type=queue destination=*NameofQueue1* routing_key=*RoutingKey1*
```

by executing rabbitmqadmin.exe -help -subcommands it lists all the available commands

eg: c:\python26\python.exe rabbitmqadmin.exe -help -subcommands

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more minimal Python example, taken from the [RabbitMQ Python tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html).

First, install pika:

```sh
sudo easy_install pika
# (or use pip)
```

This is all you need to send a message to localhost:

```py
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='test-queue')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='test-queue', body='Hello World!')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, my RabbitMQ Management deal kept trying to redirect to the https version... everything in my setup is vanilla, I don't even have a config file... anyways, my work around was to manually create `rabbitmqadmin.py` in the `sbin` folder, then fill it with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.8.1/bin/rabbitmqadmin

Then, make sure that `python` is in your `PATH` and run this to, for example, add an exchange:

```
python rabbitmqadmin.py declare exchange --vhost=/ name=CompletedMessageExchange type=direct
```

Answer (score 0):

If any windows user looking for powershell based solution then there is the function I have written.

```
Function createQueue([string]$QueueName){
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("content-type", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic Z3Vlc3Q6Z3Vlc3Q=")

$body = "{
`n  `"vhost`": `"/`",
`n  `"name`": `"$QueueName`",
`n  `"durable`": `"true`",
`n  `"arguments`": {}
`n}"

# Write-Host $body

$url='http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/'+$QueueName

# Write-Host  $url

$response = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method 'PUT' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

Save this into helper.ps1 file and include it into your script like this

```
$queueNames = 'my-queue-name'

. .\helper.ps1

createQueue($queueName)
```

Answer (score -1):

### Walkthrough to Create and delete a queue in RabbitMQ:

I couldn't find a commandline command to do it.  Here is how I did it in code with java.

Rabbitmq-server version `3.3.5` on Ubuntu.

**List the queues, no queues yet:**

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
[sudo] password for eric:
Listing queues ...
...done.
```

**Put this in CreateQueue.java**

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import java.util.*;
public class CreateQueue {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("x-message-ttl", 60000);
    channel.queueDeclare("kowalski", false, false, false, args);
    channel.close();
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

**Supply the jar file that came with your rabbitmq installation:**

I'm using rabbitmq-client.jar version 0.9.1, use the one that comes with your version of rabbitmq.

Compile and run:

```
javac -cp .:rabbitmq-client.jar CreateQueue.java
java -cp .:rabbitmq-client.jar CreateQueue
```

**It should finish without errors, check your queues now:**

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...
kowalski        0
...done.
```

the kowalski queue exists.

Answer (score -2):

helps to bind the exchange while you're at it:

```
channel.queue_bind(queueName, exchange)
```

C-;