# How do I delete all messages from a single queue using the CLI?

Tags: rabbitmq

How do I delete all messages from a single queue using the cli?
I have the queue name and I want to clean it.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

[rabbitmqadmin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) is the perfect tool for this

```
rabbitmqadmin purge queue name=name_of_the_queue_to_be_purged
```

Comment: I had a hard time finding the tool in my rabbitmq installation. I finally downloaded it from here: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_5/bin/rabbitmqadmin

Comment: If you have the management plugin already installed, you can downloaded it from `http://rabbitserver:15672/cli/`

Comment: Also to list available queues try

rabbitmqctl list_queues

Answer (score 194):

you can directly run this command

```
sudo rabbitmqctl purge_queue queue_name
```

Comment: or, if you have a virtual host, do `rabbitmqctl purge_queue queue_name -p my_virt_host`

Comment: run sudo rabbitmqctl -h  and  check list of cammand listed by  your  current rabbitmq. if it is not there  it means current version of rabbitmq does not support this feature.

Comment: This didn't work for me -- as soon as my consumer fired up, the queue was still full of tasks.

Comment: This could have been implemented in either 3.5.4 or 3.6.0, based on https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/215 and https://www.rabbitmq.com/changelog.html . If you have an older version, rabbitmqadmin as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/18267342/272387 might help.

Comment: ...and checking in https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/rabbitmq_v3_5_4 , this feature appeared in 3.5.4.

Answer (score 30):

RabbitMQ has 2 things under queue

1. Delete
2. Purge

Delete - will delete the queue

Purge - This will empty the queue (meaning removes messages from the queue but queue still exists)

Comment: It might seem simple, but this was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 18):

To purge queue you can use following command (more information in API doc):

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -XDELETE http://localhost:15672/api/queues/vhost_name/queue_name/contents
```

Comment: Kind of scary how well this worked. Any way to protect against this happening unintentionally? Such as a config for production servers that disables this functionality to prevent accidental data loss?

Comment: Yeah, the protection would be to delete the user "guest" using the "delete_user" command

Answer (score 16):

RabbitMQ implements the Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP) so you can use generic tools for stuff like this.

On Debian/Ubuntu or similar system, do:

```
sudo apt-get install amqp-tools
amqp-delete-queue -q celery  # where celery is the name of the queue to delete
amqp-declare-queue -d -q celery # where celery is the name of the queue to delete and the "-d" creates a durable/persistent queue
```

Edit 2022: Added amqp-declare-queue to the example

Comment: That's a good solution for some version do not have rabbitmqadmin.

Comment: This deletes the whole queue, doesn't just purge it. So the queue doesn't exist anymore and you have to re-initialize the empty queue afterwards.

Comment: That's true. Luckily, ampq-tools also has a command to create a queue. The intention of this Answer was to show how we can achieve what the question asks using generic tools or when getting rabbitmqadmin isn't feasible.

Answer (score 8):

IMPORTANT NOTE: This will delete all users and config.

ALERT !!

ALERT !!

I don't suggest this answer until unless you want to delete data from all of the queues, including users and configs.
Just Reset it !!!

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Comment: That also resets your users and other configs!

Comment: I used this as part of unit tests. e.g. I clear everything, then set it all up programmically via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545660/rabbitmq-creating-queues-and-bindings-from-a-command-line/25915568#25915568 then populate some messages and do black box testing to make sure messages went through. Works great for this purpose. :)

Comment: zeroing your storage and reinstalling the OS also gets rid of the data; this is not what OP is asking

Answer (score 6):

In order to **delete only messages** from the queue use :

```
sudo rabbitmqctl --node <nodename> purge_queue <queue_name>
```

In order to **delete a queue** which is empty(*--if-empty*) or has no consumers(*--if-unused*) use :

```
sudo rabbitmqctl --node <nodename> delete_queue <queue_name> --if-empty
```

or

```
sudo rabbitmqctl --node <nodename> delete_queue <queue_name> --if-unused
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess its late but for others reference, this can be done with pika

```
import pika
host_ip = #host ip
channel = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host_ip,
                                                        5672,
                                                        "/",
credentials=pika.PlainCredentials("username","pwd"))).channel()
print "deleting queue..", channel.queue_delete(queue=queue_name)
```

Comment: hi @prajnavantha is pika has any method clear message only? (not delete queue)

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using RabbitMQ with Docker your steps should be:

1. Connect to container: docker exec -it your_container_id bash
2. rabbitmqctl purge_queue Queue-1 (where Queue-1 is queue name)

Comment: Why would it be different if one would purge the queue from outside the docker container? Isn't the queue completely oblivious to **whom** (or rather **what**) is using it? I am not suggesting anything, I am just asking.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully used `ampq-purge` from [amqp-utils](https://github.com/dougbarth/amqp-utils) to do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/dougbarth/amqp-utils.git
cd amqp-utils
# extracted from Rakefile
echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'amqp', '~> 0.7.1'
gem 'trollop', '~> 1.16.2'
gem 'facets', '~> 2.9'
gem 'clio', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'json', '~> 1.5'
gem 'heredoc_unindent', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'msgpack', '~> 0.4.5'" > Gemfile
bundle install --path=$PWD/gems
export RUBYLIB=.
export GEM_HOME=$PWD/gems/ruby/1.9.1

ruby bin/amqp-purge -v -V /vhost -u user -p queue
# paste password at prompt
```

Answer (score 1):

My `rabbitmqclt` was an older version without purge_queue, and I did not have  `rabbitmqadmin` installed.

Our app runs on celery and it has this command that worked:

```
celery -A <app_name> -Q <queue_name> purge
```