# Rabbitmqctl usage to do configuration

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am using RabbitMq on windows. I am trying to explore rabbitmqctl options.
i could see options to purge queue, create and delete shovels.

can you please tell me the rabbitmqctl usage to,
1. Create and delete exchange
2. Create and delete queues.
3. Bind and unbind queues.

i am trying to write scripts that can automate all the configurations based on input.

Comment: Can anybody please answer ..

Answer (score 0):

Look at [rabbitmqadmin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) tool, it ships with RabbitMQ Management Plugin. It can declare/delete exchanges/queues/bindings.
Also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545660/rabbitmq-creating-queues-and-bindings-from-a-command-line) and this [post](https://www.compose.com/articles/configuring-rabbitmq-exchanges-queues-and-bindings-part-2/).

Just google "rabbitmqadmin **your action**"

Also you can use [Management REST API](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_9/priv/www/api/index.html)